# .net Identity SignInManager and HttpContext.User.Identity relationship

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

in a controller method i call:

`SignInResult result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(username, password, false, false);`

it performs the login successfully, but just after (in the same method execution) if i check the content of `HttpContext.User.Identity` this object is empty.

If i call another api method and i inspect the content of  `HttpContext.User.Identity` this time is filled correctly with the logged user info.

Why this is visible only to the subsequential calls and how i can get the identity just after(in the same method) of the login `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync`

Answer (score 1):

The `User` is set in the [AuthenticationMiddleware](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/36fb1134f5c9c6f53e9ef5b7db2ab0efda2f4592/src/Security/Authentication/Core/src/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs#L57), which is executed before the controllers (see [Middleware order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#middleware-order)).

Since you can check if the login has succeeded, you should be fine by just getting the user yourself, e.g. using the [UserManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.usermanager-1):

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
}
```